# Unable to mount a gpt partitioned external USB drive in Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: linux, mount, partition, usb, usb-drive

I'm trying to mount an external Toshiba USB drive in Ubuntu 19.04. No entry appears in the file manager gui when the drive is plugged in. fdisk shows...

```
ewan@tiny:~$ sudo fdisk -l
...
Disk /dev/sdb: 698.7 GiB, 750156374016 bytes, 1465149168 sectors
Disk model: External USB 3.0
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX [redacted]
```

I used gdisk to partition the drive, and listing partitions shows:

```
Command (? for help): p
Disk /dev/sdb: 1465149168 sectors, 698.6 GiB
Model: External USB 3.0
Sector size (logical/physical): 512/512 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
Main partition table begins at sector 2 and ends at sector 33
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 1465149134
Partitions will be aligned on 2048-sector boundaries
Total free space is 2014 sectors (1007.0 KiB)
Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1            2048      1465149134   698.6 GiB   8300  Linux filesystem
```

The partition changes were saved with the gdisk 'w' command.

Using lsblk shows (drive info redacted):

```
ewan@tiny:~$ lsblk -fa
...
loop22 squashfs                                                    0   100% /snap/gnome-system-m
loop23 squashfs                                                    0   100% /snap/gnome-characte
sda                                                                         
├─sda1 vfat           XXXXXXXXX                               503.4M     1% /boot/efi
├─sda2 ext4           XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX    412.8M    34% /boot
└─sda3 crypto_L       XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX                  
  └─sda3_crypt
       LVM2_mem       XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX                
    ├─ubuntu--vg-root
    │  ext4           XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX    110.5G    47% /
    └─ubuntu--vg-swap_1
       swap           XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX                  [SWAP]
sdb                                                                         
└─sdb1
```

When I try to mount:

```
ewan@tiny:~$ sudo mount /dev/sdb /media/usb/
NTFS signature is missing.
Failed to mount '/dev/sdb': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/sdb' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?
```

Any suggestions please?

Comment: What happens if you try to mount `/dev/sdb1`?

Comment: Can you add the output of lsblk -fa to your answer

Comment: @Hermann `sudo mount  /dev/sdb1 /media/usb` gives the same error message as for mounting /dev/sdb (albeit referring to /dev/sdb1 of course)

Comment: @Qasim Added. Shows clearly the whole-disk device (/dev/sdb) and partition  (/dev/sdb1) as per answer below

Comment: It seems you havent added a filesystem on your sdb disk, you should first add a filesystem then try to mount after. To create a NTFS filesystem use **mkfs.ntfs /dev/sdb**, After this you should mount using **/dev/sdb1 /media/usb**, Reply to me if this does or does no work please.

Comment: Yes, thanks, it worked as per @telcoM below.

Comment: @Ewan nice just remember the 3 steps to disks in linux, 1) partition, 2) add filesystem 3) mount (or add entry to fstab for automatic mounting)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`gdisk` just modifies the partition table, it does not actually create the filesystem metadata structures into new partitions (aka "formatting" the partition). For that, you'll need some variant of the `mkfs` command.

As you've created a partition `/dev/sdb1` and marked it as a Linux filesystem, you should now create the filesystem of the desired type on it. For example, if you choose to use the `ext4` filesystem type, you should run `sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdb1`; if you chose XFS instead, you should run `sudo mkfs.xfs /dev/sdb1` instead.

After the `mkfs` command is successfully executed, the filesystem should be ready for mounting. And you should use the partition device (`/dev/sdb1`), not the whole-disk device (`/dev/sdb`) for mounting.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks very much, I created an ext4 filesystem as above.